# Best Platform to develop QGIS Python Plugins

Tags: qgis-plugins, development, python-2.7

I am currently developing QGIS Python Plugins in a Windows 7 64-bit environment.

Having said this I am stumbling across various issues which from what I have been able to gather have a less tendency of happening in the other platforms (i.e. Linux and OSX Mac).

I would like to ask the community to answer the following question:

**What is the best platform to develop QGIS Python Plugins?**

Thanks

Comment: Which issues have you run into?

Comment: As per my comment below "underdark"'s answer, the issue which has led me to raise this question is that of how to debug QGIS python plugins in a Windows 7 64-bit environment

Answer (score 1):

I develop Python plugins on both Windows (with OSGeo4W) and Ubuntu (through repos) and I don't see a difference.

I wouldn't advise to use the stand-alone installer on Windows though and you will have to be careful if your code depends on Python packages which are not installed by default.

If you could be more specific about the problems you've encountered, maybe we can help with those.

Comment: The great thing about Python is 97% of the time it is agnostic about platform.  Use what you are comfortable with, if you don't use Linux often, then you just extended your development time.

Comment: Basically I am new to both developing in Python and developing QGIS Python Plugins and after some tedious back and forth I have got a very basic plugin functioning properly.

The problem I am now having is that certain functions I am using do not appear to be working or certain cases scenario are not going as expected.

I have been looking into setting up a Debugger to be able to debug a QGIS Plugin but I am having problems in this respect, and hence why I have asked the above question.

Comment: @CedricRamirez You should ask how to setup a debugger if that's what your real question is.

Comment: @underdark Of course I would ask this question but before I ventured forward into asking that I wanted to get the community's opinion on the suggested/recommended platform to develop QGIS plugins and hence my question